# Problema com o basico da criação de um sidenav usando Materializecss

Tags: css, materialize

Estou aprendendo a materializecss e estou tentando criar um `sidenav`, mas estou tendo problemas, gostaria de saber onde, segue o pequeno código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Materialize</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a class="btn" data-activates="slide-out"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').sidenav();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando abro o navegador, está do seguinte jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É um código tão simples, mas não estou entendendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que seja por que vc está usando o componente de uma versão mais o CSS/JS de outra versão.

Veja aqui a documentação da versão **1.0.0-rc.2** que é a que vc está indexando no `<head>` do documento: https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html

Repare que no btn que ativa o `sidebar` vc chama assim: `data-activates="slide-out"` e deveria ser assim: `data-target="slide-out"`

Outo problema é que seu script referencia o proprio btn, pq vc escreveu assim:  `$('.btn').sidenav();` e deveria ser assim: `$('.sidenav').sidenav();`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Materialize</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>



    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
      
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger btn"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```